# crash took place when new context was created in MFC

Tags: mfc, v8

v8 version : 10.5.0

IDE : vs2022

I am trying to embed v8 in MFC. To test simply, I created a dialog project, initialized v8 on `OnInitDialog()`, disposed it `OnDestroy()`. And then, I wrote the code to create the context in `BN_CLICKED` event and run script("Hello World!)". So, when the button was pressed, I wanted to show "Hello World!". But the crash took place in the code that create the context(`v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr);`).

As a result of testing, this only happens in MFC. This crash does not happen in console programs.

Somebody, anybody help me~. there is my whole code below.

**cpp**

```cpp
BOOL Cv8TestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    ...

    // Initialize V8.
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation("");
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData("");
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.

    m_create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    m_isolate = v8::Isolate::New(m_create_params);

    return TRUE;
}

void Cv8TestDlg::OnDestroy()
{
    CDialogEx::OnDestroy();

    m_isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::DisposePlatform();
    delete m_create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
}

void Cv8TestDlg::OnRun()
{
    CString text;
    v8::Isolate* isolate = m_isolate;

    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    // Create a new context.
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr);

    // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    {
        // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
        v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'");

        // Compile the source code.
        v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

        // Run the script to get the result.
        v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

        // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
        v8::String::Value utf8(isolate, result);
        text = (LPCWSTR)*utf8;
    }

    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(text);
}
```

**h**

```cpp
class Cv8TestDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    ...

    v8::Isolate::CreateParams m_create_params;
    v8::Isolate* m_isolate = nullptr;

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();

    ...

    afx_msg void OnDestroy();
    afx_msg void OnRun();
};
```

crash call stack

```
v8.dll!v8::internal::tracing::TraceEventHelper::GetTracingController() 
v8.dll!v8::NewContext(v8::Isolate * external_isolate, v8::ExtensionConfiguration * extensions, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate> global_template, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> global_object, unsigned __int64 context_snapshot_index, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback embedder_fields_deserializer, v8::MicrotaskQueue * microtask_queue) line 6391    C++
v8.dll!v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate * external_isolate, v8::ExtensionConfiguration * extensions, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate> global_template, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> global_object, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback internal_fields_deserializer, v8::MicrotaskQueue * microtask_queue) line 6413   C++
v8Test.exe!Cv8TestDlg::OnRun() line 198 C++
```

exception message

`(0x00007FFADBB43D53(v8.dll), v8Test.exe): 0xC0000005: 0x0000000000000088 access violation`

break position(trace-event.cc)

```cpp
v8::TracingController* TraceEventHelper::GetTracingController() {
->  return v8::internal::V8::GetCurrentPlatform()->GetTracingController();
}
```

Comment: People use the term *"crash"* to describe all sorts of unexpected program behavior. Please provide details on what exactly is happening. If you see an error dialog provide its contents (you can usually get a text-version of the dialog onto the clipboard by pressing Ctrl+C). If you get an exception when running under a debugger, show the full call stack from the IDE.

Comment: thank you for your interest~. I added  the calll stack, and so on.

Comment: That's better, though the access violation has more information. Specifically, it should include the attempted memory access (read/write/execute). That's useful in understand, which part of the code triggers the exception. Please add that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform` in `OnInitDialog`. The purpose of a `std::unique_ptr` is to destroy the thing it points at when the pointer goes out of scope (i.e. in this case, at the end of the function). The `v8::Platform` should be long-lived, all the way until the `v8::V8::DisposePlatform()` call.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, and would perfectly explain, why `GetCurrentPlatform()` would return a null pointer, that's subsequently dereferenced.